# VB.NET project upgrade VS2005 to VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I have a VB.NET 2.0 project developed using VS2005 Free Edition and I am considering to upgrade it to VS2008 FE, mainly because I have problems once per year, whenever my Temporary Certificate [expires](http://support.microsoft.com/Default.aspx?kbid=925521).

I was wondering if you can point to some resources describing in what parts of the code I should pay attention after the upgrade. My project uses only two external components ([zipforge](http://www.componentace.com/.NET_zip_component_zipforge.htm) and [objectlistview](http://www.teamjohnston.net/blogs/jesse/category/ObjectListView.aspx)) and I am not using any databases, in case this information is of any use to your answers.

Comment: There's nothing to do. Just open the project. What made you think this would take an effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with the .NET 2.0 framework once you upgrade to 2008, click on My Project in the Solution Explorer, select the Compile tab, Advanced Complile Options button, Target Framework drop down box. If you don't do this, the project defaults to using the latest framework, 3.5, which could cause problems when you deploy upgraded exes if you inadvertantly start using 3.5 only features and your target PCs don't have 3.5 installed. Changing this option before you start making changes to your source prevents you using 3.5 only features.

Answer (score 5):

Try to open your project in VS2008, the wizard will ask you whether you want to convert your project, you hit yes, then point - to create backup, and show log after conversion.
At the end wizard will show you conversion results. If any error will occur, you'll be able to clearly see its location. 
then it will be up to you if you want to upgrade project to .NET 3.5 version, but if no - fine, VS 2008 has .NET 2.0 support as well.

Comment: Hi @Sorantis , i have the same scenario where i want to upgrade my project from vs2005 to vs2008 , but when i open my vs2005 project to vs2008 , it did not ask me to convert, i mean there is not conversion wizard appears , what pop'up appears is asking me if i want to convert into .Net 3.5 , but since i dont want yet, i select no , and it opens without problem.. now my question is, is it ok ? that there is no conversion appears ? , it is like that i change my IDE into vs2008 and not converted, something like that... any idea on this ? , Regards :)